# Using php in a jsp file to access the Full Calendar Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, spring, rest, jsp

I have been trying to implement the Full Calendar plugin into a spring maven project. I have been using php and JavaScript to access the plugin. The JavaScript code is a jsp file which is shown below. The jsp file is being accessed through the controller class. When I run the program the HTML code works but the php part of the file will not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />

<link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/custom.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>

<?php
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();


  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },


   events: "events.php",


   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');


   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'add_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
       alert('Added Successfully');
       }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
       title: title,
       start: start,
       end: end,
       allDay: allDay
   },
   true
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },


   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'update_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
        alert("Updated Successfully");
       }
   });
   },
   eventClick: function(event) {
    var decision = confirm("Do you really want to do that?"); 
    if (decision) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_event.php",
        data: "&id=" + event.id,
         success: function(json) {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
              alert("Updated Successfully");}
    });
    }
    },
   eventResize: function(event) {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       $.ajax({
        url: 'update_events.php',
        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(json) {
         alert("Updated Successfully");
        }
       });
    }

  });

 });
?>

</script>
<style>
 body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  }
 #calendar {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

When I call it in the Controller class the javascript portion will not work:

```
@Controller
public class EventController { 

  @RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String event() {
      return "index";
  }
}
```

I have tried to use a php file instead of a jsp file but that has just been giving me 404 errors no matter what I have tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've placed in the PHP tags isn't PHP - it's JavaScript. Just remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I removed it but I am still getting the blank screen for some reason. It is not accessing the javascript code. @Michael Hodgins

Comment: Can you see if any HTML is being delivered to the browser and are there any error messages in the browser's console?